# Why is foundation not being loaded via sprockets on middleman

Tags: ruby, bower, sprockets, middleman

I have this middleman project.

I have added foundation to it with bower.

So my folder structure is like this:

```
-myproject
 -source
  -bower_components
   -foundation(css, js and scss folder are in here)
```

I have added these two lines to my config.rb as suggested in the documentation in **Sprockets import path** : https://middlemanapp.com/basics/asset-pipeline/

```
sprockets.append_path File.join root, 'bower_components'
sprockets.import_asset 'foundation'
```

Then on my layout.erb I have my stylesheet linked like this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "all", "normalize" %>
```

all.css has only this inside:

```
@charset "utf-8";
```

But i cant use foundation... is not being recognized any ideas ?

Here is my project in github if you need to see something else: https://github.com/GiorgioMartini/thisisgiorgio

thanks.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42999918/938261

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try moving your `bower_components` directory into the root of your project (so that it's a child of `myproject`, not a child of `source`). That should correspond to the path you passed into `sprockets.append_path`.