# Middleman using Foundation 6

Tags: middleman, zurb-foundation-6, middleman-4

I want to use Middleman with wonderful Foundation 6. [Here](https://github.com/james-weaver/middleman-zurb-foundation-6) is a repo I've found on Middleman's website.

I have Middleman installed as well as Xcode developers tools.
When I run `middleman init -T james-weaver/middleman-foundation-6 portfolio` in my Terminal I get `Unknown Project Template` error.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install **foundation-sites** (v6) at the root of your Middleman project, using NPM:

```
cd middleman-project
npm init -y
npm install foundation-sites --save
```

Then, at the file `source/stylesheets/site.css.scss`, add:

```
@import '../../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/foundation';
@include foundation-everything;
```

It works! Finally, you could look at the file `foundation.scss` and customize what is loaded by `foundation-everything`.