# Sass only including comments from foundation partial in compiled css

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation, jekyll

I'm trying to make a jekyll blog using foundation and sass, and I just can't seem to get the foundation sass to compile correctly. When I build jekyll, there are no errors, and the partial I wrote seems to load correctly, and foundation seems to import, but only the comments at the top.

My process so far was basically to run 
`npm install foundation-sites --save`

move the foundation sass stuff out of the node_modules folder, and then include foundation in my scss file.

You can see the directory and the css file that is output in the following screenshots. 
[image]

[image]

I'm kind of not sure what else I can try at this point any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Edit: Here is a link to the branch and repo for this to see the code. https://github.com/samuraiseoul/kimchiChingu/tree/23-sass

Comment: A repository url maybe ?

Comment: Yes this needs more information to check what is happening in your app.scss, because its actually different from the main.scss name, and I don't see a compiled css file also in the css folder. Remember that sass looks for the scss "main file" which in yoru case I believe it is "app.scss" which should have the @imports of the partials or whatever you want to compile to a NEW app.CSS file. So you might want to share some more information on how you are doing that ?

Comment: @DavidJacquel @Leo Here's a link to the branch on the repo with the sass files in it. I also edited the question to have the link as well. You should be able to clone it and run `jekyll build` to get it running. Thanks so much for our help and if you have any other questions please just let me know and I can add the required information. 

https://github.com/samuraiseoul/kimchiChingu/tree/23-sass

Comment: Which OS are you using?  Which version of jekyll, ruby, and node?

Comment: @KrisKrause I'm using Linux Ubuntu 16.04, Jekyll 3.4.0 and Ruby 2.3.1 as well as node 3.5.2

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42999918/938261

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so I figured it out. The problem is that I had to either include the foundation-everything mixin in my sass file or the specific modules I wanted.

just using `@import 'foundation';` wasn't good enough, I had to also put `@include foundation-everything;` or list each component I wanted in case I didn't want everything.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm.. it seems like all the partials imported in `foundation.scss` are just sass functions, mixins and variables. So there's no actual css output.

Comment: Hrmmm, I used npm to generate the foundation stuff though and didn't really delete anything. Is there a different way to get foundation in the project that's better?

Comment: If you don't really want to change the original foundation CSS, you could just include `foundation.scss` and replace all the @include with minified foundation css file. To override the styles you can add another .scss file in the _sass folder and use @include after  '@include: 'foundation''; in your main.scss. For example you would then have foundation.scss and custom.scss in your _sass file. In main.scss you would then have to write `@include: 'foundation'; @include: 'custom';`. This way your custom styles would overwrite the original foundations CSS. Hope this helps :)

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now in the main branch, but I don't want to do that because for a few things that works, but for something like the main color or another, if I want to change that in the whole project then I have to regenerate a full min.css from the foundation site and remember all my previous value. I want to get this working via scss so I don't have to include a lot of things I don't want, and can change things more easily in the future. Do you know how I can get this working via the foundation sass files?

Comment: I guess you could try doing this with some kind of task runner like Gulp or Grunt? [Here](https://github.com/core77/jekyll-foundation) is a repo on Github that I found that looks like has what you need - Foundation SASS and Jekyll.

Comment: Yes but that is for starting a new project, i'm adding foundation to an existing jekyll project. Also Jekyll has something to compile the SASS into it, so I don't need to run the task I wouldn't think as it already get's compiled.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue even after adding

```
@include foundation-everything($flex: false);
```

I figured it out after updating my gulp-sass module.

Comment: We may have had a different foundation version. Either way thanks for documenting another fix here. :D